# Hanging indentation of source code within sentence a la Vim-LaTeX-Box

Tags: best-practices, sourcecode, source

I've recently been playing with the LaTex-Box plugin for Vim and noticed the layout of the source code on their [Github page](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box):
[image: sexy source code]

What interests me is the 2-space hanging indent within each sentence. That would be a massive pain unless something automatic like `gq` handled it. But I haven't been able to find anything mentioning it and any formatting commands using LaTeX-Box (assuming I've got it set up correctly) have not resulted in the hanging indent.

Is there something I've screwed up with LaTeX-Box, or is there some other script/plugin/etc. that does this? Maybe just a mapping/function of some kind? Again, I do *not* need general formatting/indentation, just this specific application.

Answer (score 1):

I have resorting to the following solution: a mapping to add the hanging indent, then the usual `gqq`, or whatever your preference is, to handle the word wrap. This should perpetuate the hanging indent.

Mapping in .vimrc or somewhere else if you want it to be (La)TeX specific:

`nnoremap <c-i> JgqqI<space><space><Esc>`

The visual style of breaking up the sentences has really grown on me, but I got sick of doing it manually. Hooray for Vim and bindings.

Comment: Oh no, those emacs/vim thingies again